# How do we know this is the minimum polynomial of $\alpha \in GF(p^n)$

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, minimal-polynomials

In a proof I was reading on how the Frobenius automorphism generates the Galois group of $GF(p^n)$ over $GF(p)$, it says that :

$\alpha \in GF(p^n)$, the element which we adjoin to $GF(p)$ to get $GF(p^n)$ has minimum polynomial

suppose the minimal polynomial of 
α
has degree 
t
; then it has the following form:

$$m(x)=(x-\alpha)(x-\alpha^{p})(x-\alpha^{p^2})……(x-\alpha^{p^{t-1}})$$

How is this known ? I looked back at my rings and field course and my linear algebra course but it wasn't proven there either.

Many thanks for any help !

Comment: What is $\alpha$? What is $t$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I've edited it now

Comment: Your edits don't answer the question. Is $\alpha$ the element you adjoint to $GF(p)$ to get $GF(p^n)$? (Also, don't use $P$ and $p$ interchangeably; pick one and stick to it!) Some other element? An arbitrary element of $GP(p^n)$? Saying $t$ is the degree of the minimal polynomial doesn't really answer the question, either. Is it determined in terms of $\alpha$? Or do you say "suppose the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ has degree $t$; then it has the following form:" ? You need to provide all the context. "In a proof I was reading" is fine for you, but we don't have access to what you read.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I've edited it again. I find it difficult to know sometimes how much context is needed with those types of terms particularly because I'm only learning so I often assume more experienced mathematicians understand it contextually. Sorry for the confusion, it had not been clearly stated in the proof I was reading but I think the proof I'm reading may not be very clear due to the author (my lecturer) making the exact mistake I made and not being clear enough about what these symbols mean, his notes often feel like that.. hopefully my latest edit is completely clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Remark:** I'll prove the more general claim that if $\alpha \in GF(P^n)$ then it's minimal polynomial can be factored as $(x-\alpha)(x-\alpha^p)\cdots(x-\alpha^{p^{t-1}})$, where $t$ is the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $GF(P)$. If you take $\alpha$ to be the element we adjoin to $GF(P)$ in order to obtain $GF(P^n)$ we have that $t=n$ and everything else is the same.

---

Use the fact that the $GF(P)$ has characteristic $p$ and so we have that $a^p + b^p = (a+b)^p$ for any $a,b \in GF(P)$. In particular this gives you $a^p = a$ for $a \in GF(P)$.

Now let $x^t + a_1x^{t-1} + \cdots + a_t = 0$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $GF(P)$. Then note that $a^p$ is a root too. Indeed using what I mentioned above we have:

$$(\alpha^p)^t + a_1(\alpha^p)^{t-1} + \cdots + a_t = (\alpha^t)^p + (a_1\alpha^{t-1})^p + \cdots + a_t^p = (\alpha^t + a_1\alpha^{t-1} + \cdots + a_t)^p = 0$$

In a similar manner you have that $(\alpha^p)^p = \alpha^{p^2}$ is a root, too. As well as $\alpha^{p^k}$ for any integer $k$.

Finally, you need to prove that $\alpha^{p^i} \not = \alpha^{p^j}$ for $0 \le i< j \le t-1$. Otherwise we have $\alpha^{p^j - p^i} - 1 = 0$. This means that $\alpha$ has order less than $p^{t-1} - 1$. However adjoining $\alpha$ to $GF(P)$ yields $GF(P^t)$ and $\alpha$ is the generator of the group of units of $GF(P^t)$, which has order $p^t - 1$. Thus $\alpha$ has order $p^t - 1$, which contradicts the claim above.

Hence $\{\alpha^{p^k} \mid 0 \le k \le t-1 \}$ are the distinct roots of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $GF(P)$.